# Issues installing Spring STS in Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm on Windows 7 professional 64b and have just downloaded and installed Eclipse Juno 64b:

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Juno Service Release 2
Build id: 20130225-0426
```

I go to Help -> Eclipse Marketplace then search for `Spring STS` and choose `STS for Eclipse Juno (3.8 + 4.2)` at this point I get into a deadly loop of not found dependencies and it doesn't matter how many packages I deselect, it will always complain (see below).

I have also tried installing Eclipse for Java Developers instead of Java EE. I have also tried the 32b versions. Finally I have also tried installing from the Spring STS update site  http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.2/ and still no luck.

Can anyone advice what's the solution to this problem? maybe I should switch back to Indigo?

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Spring IDE Spring Data Support 3.2.0.201303060654-RELEASE     
(org.springframework.ide.eclipse.data.feature.feature.group 3.2.0.201303060654-RELEASE)
  Missing requirement: Spring IDE Live Beans Graph 3.2.0.201303060654-RELEASE     
(org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.ui.livegraph 3.2.0.201303060654-RELEASE) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.zest.core [1.0.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Spring IDE Spring Data Support 3.2.0.201303060654-RELEASE     
(org.springframework.ide.eclipse.data.feature.feature.group 3.2.0.201303060654-RELEASE)
To: org.springframework.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 0.0.0
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Spring IDE Core (required) 3.2.0.201303060654-RELEASE     (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 3.2.0.201303060654-RELEASE)
To: org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.ui.livegraph [3.2.0.201303060654-RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually avoid the Eclipse download site altogether and get the Spring Tool Suite IDE directly from here: http://www.springsource.org/downloads/sts-ggts. Everything I needed worked smoothly and out of the box: importing Maven projects and running the applications using AspectJ/Spring. It also comes with the critically needed plugins e.g. EGit, m2e, AJDT and everything works perfectly.

I needed this for a new GUI project on top of Spring/Valkyrie RCP.